# Resolv.conf file gets rewrited everytime

Tags: resolv.conf

On my lubuntu 20.04 LTS I disabled the resolved service before I installed pihole (as dns server for my home network) which in turn installed dnsmasq too. I also modified the resolv.conf file to enable lubuntu to resolve query requests for its update or any other requests for its own use, but the file resolv.conf get rigenerated at every boot as it was, that is:

```
Generated by NetworkManager

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I had tried to set it this way:

```
Generated by NetworkManager

nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Before that, I had also modified the file 01-network-manager-all.yaml in the folder /etc/netplan

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
   enp6s0:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [192.168.3.94/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.3.1
    nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I don't know what else to do in order to set permanently the dns server ip in the resolv.conf file.
Could you help me figure this out please?

Comment: Did you read the comments in the file and try what it said? Un-linking it being the least...

Comment: @WU-TANG Try what exactly?

Comment: the /etc/resolv.conf file has comments in it about where to find information and suggestions on how configure it in different modes... one of which is un-linking it.